# Prove that the set $H =\{1, x, y, xy\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that it has order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is from Michael Artin - Algebra (2nd Edition), Chapter 2, exercise 4.7.

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of a group $G$. Assume that each of the elements $x, y$, and $xy$ has order 2. Prove that the set $H = \{1, x, y, xy\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that it has order 4.

My approach is simply to write out the multiplication table of $H$:

$$\begin{array}{ l | c c c r }
  ~ & 1 & x & y & xy \\
    \hline
  1 & 1 & x & y & xy\\
  x & x & 1 & xy & y\\
  y & y & xy & 1 & x\\
  xy & xy & y & x & 1\\
\end{array}$$

which shows that multiplication within $H$ is totally defined using the four elements listed. Hence the criteria for a subgroup (closure, identity and inverse) are satisfied, and $H$ has order 4.

I'd like to know if the proof is acceptable and whether there are other approaches.

Edit:
Sorry for the missing justification, it should have gone as follows(in the sequence$xxy,yx,yxy,xy,xyx,xyxy$):
$$xxy=(xx)y=y$$
$$yxxy=y(xx)y=y1y=1 $$
hence
$$yx=(xy)^{-1} $$
and we know that $o(xy)=2$, so
$$yx=xy$$
Also, since
$$yxyx=xyxy=1, yxy=x^{-1}=x $$
(for o(x)=2)
Likewise$$xyx=y^{-1}=y$$
and finally
$$xyxy=(xy)(xy)=1$$

Comment: How do you know that table is accurate? In particular, how do you know that $xy$ times $x$ is equal to $y$? Or that $y$ times $x$ is $xy$? A lot of justification is missing.

Comment: Let me give you a hint to get started. We know (why?) $$ xyxy=1$$ and hence $$yxy=x^{-1}$$ and thus (why?) we get $$yxy=x.$$ You need to justify in similar fashion many of the other entries you claim without any proof.

Comment: @severin-schraven@arturo-magidin Thank you for the comment! In fact I thought them trivial.. I just made some edits and completed the justification.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

$$\begin{align}
xy&=x1y\\
&=x((xy)(xy))y\\
&=(xx)(yx)(yy)\\
&=1yx1\\
&=yx,
\end{align}$$

so $x$ and $y$ commute.
So, any word in $x$ and $y$ can be written in the form $x^ry^s$, $r=0$ or $1$, $s=0$ or $1$.
So the group generated by $x$ and $y$ has only the four elements $1,x,y,xy$.

Comment: Thank you! it seems much more orderly.